# How do I reorganize an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to reorganize an array..
I have a multidimensional array(Ill call that original_array) and I would like to take the first array within original_array and set the values as keys in a new array. I also want to take the values of the second array in original_array and make them keys and then set the values of the third array in original_array as the values for those keys.

Here is an example of original_array:

```
Array ( 
       [id] => Array ( 
                      [0] => 1 
                      [1] => 3 
                     ) 
   [reward] => Array ( 
                      [0] => Movie
                      [1] => Trip
                     ) 
     [cost] => Array ( 
                      [0] => 50 
                      [1] => 200
                     ) 
      )
```

Basically what I would like to do is look like this:

```
Array ( 
       [1] => Array ( 
                     [Movie] => 50
                    )
       [3] => Array (
                     [Trip] => 200
                    )
      )
```

Is there a simple and elegant way to merge these like this?
I have spent hours trying to figure this out using array_merge, array_merge_recursive.. etc. And have search SO far and wide for a similar questions, but I haven't found anything that does what I am after.

I was able to correctly combine the 2nd and 3rd arrays in original_array with array_combine. But, I am at a loss as how to combine that result with the 1st array's values in original_array.

Thanks in advance to any help!

Comment: So you have a two dimensional array where the first array contains the keys for the first dimension and the second array contains the keys for the second dimension? (Also are there always the right amount of elements in there for each array?)

Comment: just use a foreach create another container

Comment: In the original_array there are 3 2nd dimension arrays(ill call them sub arrays). In the first sub array I want to use values there as keys in a new array. Then combine the 2nd and 3rd sub arrays AS the second dimension for each of those keys.

Every time I need this action to happen there will be always be these 3 same sub arrays( [id], [reward], [cost] ). 

The number of elements in those might vary, but when I get the array from $_POST it will always be in that format that I used in above example (original_array)

I hope that helps clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Ghost, can you please show an example?
I have tried doing this with foreach and it is not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be some incantation of `array_*()` merging functions that could produce what you're looking for, but it is far easier to just iterate over the original array's `[id]` sub-array and use its values to create new sub-array keys in a different output array.

```
// To hold your output
$output = array();

// Iterate the original array's [id] sub-array
foreach ($original['id'] as $idxkey => $newkey) {
  // Add a sub-array using $newkey to the output array
  $output[$newkey] = array( 
    // Using the index (not value), retrieve the corresponding reward
    // value to use as the new array key
    // and corresponding cost to use as the new subarray value
    $original['reward'][$idxkey] => $original['cost'][$idxkey]
  );
}
```

Here is a demonstration: https://3v4l.org/2pac3

Comment: Feel like this is the simplest solution OP can get ;) Even though the solution from Ghost is also nice with a bit of a *hacky* `array_chunk()` call there.

Comment: If I think hard enough, I can usually come up with some combination of array methods, but honestly in practice I just prefer the loop because I can understand it immediately when I come back to it later.

Comment: All of these did work. Though like you both said, this is very simple and easy to understand. I was trying to get it to work like this earlier, however was getting tripped up on the last line. Thank so much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Well, the dirty way would be just use combine array functions like `array_combine` with the input:

```
$new_array = array_combine(
    $array['id'], // parent keys
    // combine chunked combined sub keys :p
    array_chunk(array_combine($array['reward'], $array['cost']), 1, true)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

First you can get the keys for the main array into a separate variable with `array_shift()`, which will just remove the first element from your array, which is the array holding the keys.

Then use `array_map()` to loop through both of your subArrays and use `reward` as key with the `cost` values as value and return it in an array. At the end you just have to `array_combine()` your keys `$keys` with the new created array.

Code:

```
<?php

    $keys = array_shift($arr);

    $result = array_combine($keys, array_map(function($k, $v){
        return [$k => $v];
    }, $arr["reward"], $arr["cost"]));


    print_r($result);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You might wanna take a look at [`BaseArrayHelper`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseArrayHelper.php) from Yii 2.0 Framework.

Although this file is part of a framework it has only very few dependencies and you should be able to use just this file or parts of it in your code with small modifications.

An example for your use case can be found in the [`index()` method](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseArrayHelper.php#L243-L367).